# Fail to use Manifest to to extract data with json4s

Tags: scala, playframework, manifest, scalatest, json4s

I have simple function that takes a string json and extract it to case class, it looks like this:

```
type ExtractionType

implicit def extractionManifest: Manifest[ExtractionType]


def myExctractionFunc: List[FinalModel] = {

val mylist: List[FinalType] = parse(response.body).extract[ExtractionType]

...

}
```

Now, theres are 2 services (in different classes) that are using this function and each one is implementing `ExtractionType` and `extractionManifest` differently.

BUT, for one service it works perfect, and for the other im getting the error:

> The future returned an exception of type:
>   org.json4s.package$MappingException, with message: unknown error.

(`myExctractionFunc` is using futures and more complex stuff so I simplified it, this is why the error mention future)

the implementation of the service that fail to extract is:

```
case class  Person (name: String, age: Int)

override type ExtractionType = List[Person]

override implicit val inManifest = Manifest.classType[List[Person]](classOf[List[Person]])
```

the service that succeed looks like this:

```
case class Animal(kindOfAnimal: String, age: Int)

case class JungleObjects(animals: List[Animal])

 override type ExtractionType = JungleObjects

  override implicit val inManifest = Manifest.classType[JungleObjects](classOf[JungleObjects])
```

does anyone can see why the one is working and the other is not?

I had to use all those case classes in my projects to separate things, I just simplified the code so the question won't be too annoying :)

thanks!

Comment: Are your case classes top-level, or defined in an object? "Only top level objects or objects defined directly in an object are supported", see https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues/125

Comment: @user2128014 i think they are top-level, I saw this example before but its not my case, i didnt define the case class inside a function, I have a model classes for each of my case classes